# How to use SERVICE_CHECK_HTTP with progrium/consul check-http script?

Tags: docker, service-discovery, health-monitoring, consul

I am running the progrium/consul container with the gliderlabs/registrator container.  I would like to be able to automatically create health checks for any container that is registered to consul with the registrator.  Using this I would like to use consul health checks to know if any container has stopped running.  I have read that there is a way to do this by adding environmental variables, but everything I have read has been far too vague, such as the post below:

[how to define HTTP health check in a consul container for a service on the same host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623590/how-to-define-http-health-check-in-a-consul-container-for-a-service-on-the-same)

So I am supposed to set some environmental variables:

```
ENV SERVICE_CHECK_HTTP=/howareyou
ENV SERVICE_CHECK_INTERVAL=5s
```

Do I set them inside of my progrium/consul container or my gliderlabs/registrator?  Would I set them by just adding the following tags inside my docker run command like this?

```
docker run ...... -e SERVICE_CHECK_HTTP=howareyou -e SERVICE_CHECK_INTERVAL=5s ......
```

**Note:** for some reason adding the above environmental variables to the docker run commands of my registrator just caused consul to think my nodes are failing from `no acks received`

Answer (score 2):

I got Consul Health Checks and Gliderlabs Registrator working in three ways with my Spring Boot apps:

- Put the environment variables in the Dockerfile with `ENV` or `LABEL`
- Put the environment variables using `-e` with `docker run`
- Put the environment variables into docker-compose.yml under "environment" or "labels"

### Dockerfile

In your Dockerfile-file:

```
ENV SERVICE_NAME MyApp
ENV SERVICE_8080_CHECK_HTTP /health
ENV SERVICE_8080_CHECK_INTERVAL 60s
```

The `/health` endpoint here is coming from the Spring Boot Actuator lib that I simply put in my pom.xml file in my Spring Boot application. You can however use any other endpoint as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

### `docker run`

```
docker run -d -e "SERVICE_NAME=myapp" -e "SERVICE_8080_CHECK_HTTP=/health" -e "SERVICE_8080_CHECK_INTERVAL=10s" -p 8080:8080 --name MyApp myapp
```

Make sure that you are using the correct HTTP server port and that it is accessible. In my case, Spring Boot uses 8080 by default.

### Docker Compose

Add the health check information under either the "environment" or "labels" properties:

```
myapp:
    image: apps/myapp
    restart: always
    environment:
     - SERVICE_NAME=MyApp
     - SERVICE_8080_CHECK_HTTP=/health
     - SERVICE_8080_CHECK_INTERVAL=60s
    ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

### Starting Consul Server

```
docker run -d -p "8500:8500" -h "consul" --name consul gliderlabs/consul-server -server -bootstrap
```

The "gliderlabs/consul-server" image activates the Consul UI by default. So you don't have to specify any other parameters.

### Then start Registrator

```
docker run -d \
    --name=registrator \
    -h $(docker-machine ip dockervm) \
    -v=/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
    gliderlabs/registrator:v6 -resync 120 -deregister on-success \
    consul://$(docker-machine ip dockervm):8500
```

The "resync" and "deregister" parameters will ensure that Consul and Registrator will be in synch.